# Singularity at z=infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)= \dfrac 1 {e^{1/z}+1}$. Does this have a removable singularity at $z=\infty$?

I found that all the singulairties (other than $\infty$) are bounded. So $z=\infty$ is a isolated singularity of $f(z)$. But does $f(1/z)=\dfrac 1 {e^{1/(1/z)}+1}=\dfrac 1 {e^{z}+1}$ have removable singularity at $z=0$ because just it has $z$ in the denominator?

Comment: I don't see any singularity at all. Certainly $1/(e^z+1)$ has no singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: @Gerry: That's true in the sense that a removable singularity is not a singularity at all, but e.g., $z\mapsto z$ has a removable singularity at $0$ if its domain is specified to be $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$, and I believe $f$ is implicitly assumed in this problem takes inputs from a subset of $\mathbb C$, hence the domain excludes $\infty$.

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps $\,\infty\,$ is automatically considered "a singularity" in every case by some authors ( I know we did so while studying this stuff )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is removable: in fact $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z) = 1/2$.

Comment: $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=a$ iff $\lim_{z\to a} (z-a)f(z)=0$,So how did you conclude that?

Comment: As $z \to \infty$, $1/z \to 0$, $e^{1/z} \to e^0 = 1$, etc.

Comment: @Tsotsi: Look at [Riemann's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem). Your characterization of a removable singularity only works for finite $a$. In his last comment, Robert Israel is using characterization 2: $f$ is continuously extendable over $a$.

Comment: Thak boss ami r parchiiina